# jQuery drag and drop selection restricted with in a Section or DIV

Tags: c#, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

i am using jquery drag and drop selection to pick up selected cells in a table. However the drag select can be done all over the web. Is there a code or method that i can restrict the drag to a particular space or DIV

Any sample code or advise to Share

Thanks so Much

Answer (score 0):

Like this

```js
  $(function() {
    $( "#draggable" ).draggable();
  });
```

```css
  #draggable, #notdraggable { width: 150px; height: 50px; padding: 0.5em; }
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

 
<div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content">
  <p>Drag me around</p>
</div>
<div id="notdraggable" class="ui-widget-content">
  <p>Cant Drag me around</p>
</div>
```